The current Ask Question Wizard leads some new users to think the prompts will be part of the question
TL;DR
Would it be possible to make users of the Ask Question Wizard more aware that only their text will be part of the question, without the prompts?
Details
In recent months, I have noticed a number of questions where the asker is using the Ask Wizard as if the questions in the wizard were going to remain visible in the posted question.
For example, this was asked today: Invalid Authentication Information
Quoting the text here in case the question gets closed and deleted:
Title:

Invalid Authentication Information

Body:

Why the response is Invalid Authentication Information when i am passing the access token? what could be the reasons?
The solution and reasons why it happened.
The token api works fine for me. But the Shipment api is the problem. it is not working as expected

As written, it's like we're reading one half of an interview and we have to guess what the questions were. My hypothesis is that the poster did not realize the prompts would be removed, and even when they reviewed the final question before posting, they didn't understand they needed to fix their question up to stand alone without the prompts.
Since I've seen this pattern a number of times recently, I would like to suggest adding a clear note when you start using the wizard that the prompts are only to help to user write a good question but are not going to be part of it.

For  the record, this has been a known problem in both revisions of the wizard. I doubt it'll ever be fixed at this point

Users are shown the following prompt at the review stage: "Your two parts were merged to make the “body” of the question. Please review and edit to make sure that the question in its entirety makes sense." It pops prominently over the input text area. The problem is that people aren't reading it; I'm not sure if adding more text would help, as they would quite likely not read that, either.

This is the 4th? 5th? question about this, the one I linked above is marked status-review (and hence in the companies issue tracker) all we can hope is that the company decides to pick it up.

@AbdulAzizBarkat I tried to find this question but had no luck. Thank you for the link, I upvoted it, and I agree my question is clearly a duplicate.

Cool, I didn't know about this feature: there was a question at the top asking me if the proposed duplicate answered my question, and clicking yes closed my question as duplicate without waiting for further review. Neato.

@RyanM Users are given a form that's functionally the same as the normal one, except it splits the main body field in two along lines that rarely if ever makes sense, and "merges" them by literally concatenating them (despite prose that implies that something reasonably intelligent will happen instead). It also forces them to fill it out in order, even though that's often a bad idea. It's not just useless, it's actively harmful to question quality.

Not only do authors not read the instructions, they don't even preview their own question.
